# How to select nested .svn folders in Total Commander?

Tags: directory, total-commander

In my project I have near 1000 nested folders. I need delete all .svn. Manually it seems takes many time. Does TotalCommander can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may:
1. Export svn from TortoiseSVN - Exporting to the same folder where project exists will delete .svn subfolders
2. search for folders named .svn (Alt+F7), put into view and delete all